# min/max slope using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

here's an example data set:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
             V1=c(30,20,10,10,30,30,15,20),
             V2=c(1:4,1:4))
```

I group by `ID`

```
df_byID <- df %>% group_by(ID)
```

I can calculate the slope of each person (ID) like this:

```
df_slope <- df_byID %>%
  do(fit = lm(V1 ~ V2, .)) %>%
  summarise(v_slope = coef(fit)[2])
```

I now want the slope of the min/max values per ID.
If V1 has several occurences of the same value I want to use the first one for max and the last one for min.

In this example we would get:

for ID=1: (10-30)/(4-1) = -6.66

for ID=2: (15-30)/(3-1) = -7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you are asking

```
df %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
summarize((max(V1) - min(V1)) / (first(V2[V1 == max(V1)]) - last(V2[V1 == min(V1)])) )
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create the `max` and `min` value index of 'V1' and then use that to calculate the 'slope.  The `which.max` gets the position of the first `max` value (if there are ties), `row_number()` is equivalent to `rank(ties.method='first')`.  So, if we change 'V1' to negative, get the `row_number`, and then get the position of `max` value by `which.max`, this would be equivalent to  finding the last 'min' value position.  Use those index, to calculate the 'slope'.

```
df_byID  %>% 
      mutate(Max = which.max(V1), Min= which.max(row_number(-V1))) %>% 
      summarise(slope= (V1[Min[1L]]-V1[Max[1L]])/(V2[Min[1L]]-V2[Max[1L]]))
#      ID     slope
#  (dbl)     (dbl)
#1     1 -6.666667
#2     2 -7.500000
```